# Way to disable liquid rendering or insert literal curly braces in a Business Catalyst page or content holder?

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

I am trying to create a simple dynamic page in Business Catalyst using Mustache templates. Mustache syntax conflicts with the liquid markup syntax, but BC provides no documentation - absolutely none - for how to disable Liquid, or insert literal curly braces on the page.

I do not want to load the Mustache templates from separate files via ajax for performance reasons, and would much prefer to have them all be inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theo's answer works, but is site-wide. To suppress Liquid Markup parsing just within (parts of) selected files, use the `{% raw -%}...{% endraw -%}` syntax. BC will not attempt to modify any Liquid syntax within those tags.

This is in the official documentation at: http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/dev-assets/reference#!/liquid-reference/reference/logic-tags.html!raw

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that, but it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid mark-up in BC is still an opt in beta feature, and you can disable this under Site Settings > Beta Features by unchecking Enable Liquid Markup.

Comment: Even this issue is not a good enough reason to disable liquid on the entire site. It is such a vast improvement.